# Show dropdown on click instead of hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Instead of showing content when hover on the dropdown, click it to show the drop down. Is this possible to do without JQuery or plugins? I have seen some example but it is a bit complicated as there is a lot of styling.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simple explanation would be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: It's a little bit more JavaScript code. Do you want to do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best non-JavaScript answer, and perhaps best solution, is to use a `input[type='checkbox']:checked + label` combination.

This way, the menu will toggle open or close only on user clicks.

Note that I made your `button` into the label. The `for` attribute must be set to the `id` of the checkbox. Also, shoot the checkbox off screen so that only the label is visible. By making it a label, set `display: block` and `cursor:pointer` to mimic the button design.

If you use the general sibling `~` and the adjacent sibling `+` selectors, you can show your menu when the checkbox is checked. See below.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropcheck {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.dropcheck:checked ~ .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropcheck:checked + .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <input id="dropcheck" class="dropcheck" type="checkbox">
  <label for="dropcheck" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</label>
  
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure. I saw the dropdown trick using checkboxes a while back but forgot the source, otherwise I'd post it. I'm glad my solution was helpful

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest you go with a Javascript route.

When the `click` event happens, add a class to the DOM and style the drop down accordingly. In this example, I'm toggling the class-name `show-menu` whenever the button is clicked.

```js
var dropDown = document.querySelector(".dropbtn");
var dropDownDiv = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
dropDown.addEventListener("click", function(){
  dropDownDiv.classList.toggle('show-menu');
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show-menu .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.show-menu .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: classList is not supported in IE versions less than 10.

Comment: this wont close the menu on click off

Answer (score -1):

Using the .div:active in css would be your solution.